# Coded UI Tests on Build Machine

Tags: azure, tfs, tfsbuild, coded-ui-tests

I am pretty new to the Coded UI Tests. From what I understand so far if I want to record a sequence of actions I have to run the project.
I want to run these tests on a build machine before deploying the code to an Azure server.
The question is how to record these tests so that it will run these coded ui tests on the build machine?
The build machine is part of TFS 2013.

Comment: Is this a web application? Regardless, you should generally speaking **not** run UI tests as part of the build process. The build process should be responsible for making binaries, running **unit** tests and some integration tests, and (if necessary) packaging the software up for release. That's it. Deploying software and running UI tests should not be done from the build.

Comment: You might also have the issue of running UI Tests on a machine with no monitor. Typically there has to be a logged in user for the UI interaction.

Comment: You can probably do it in a post build specified in the csproj (assuming you are running a cs project). Web performance tests might be worth considering as you would avoid this problem while getting a reasonable response time.

Comment: You should keep separate also the machines: the build machine should be different from the test machine.

Comment: A web search for "run coded ui test on build server" find lots of useful pages.

Answer (score 1):

You can use release management for vs to create a release pipeline that includes deploying your server to a standard lab management environment and running your coded UI tests.

http://nakedalm.com/execute-tests-release-management-visual-studio-2013/

If you use the vNext templates you have an agentless remote execution engine that can also call your powershell to upload your site to azure as post of your release pipeline.

http://nakedalm.com/create-release-management-pipeline-professional-developers/

Doing it this way will give you fill audit as well as readability to which PBI have been released

Answer (score 0):

In general UI tests are slow and can quickly have a negative impact on Build times. However, there are also cases where "protecting the source tree" is an important consideration, and one wants to prevent check-in of known broken code.

So the "answer" depends very much on what you want to accomplish as well as the environment you are working in.  Martin's suggestion of using Release Management is an excellent one, but the ramifications do need to be understood.